# probability, please help on Bayes' theorem

Tags: probability-theory

Three boxes $C_1,C_2$ and $C_3$ contain lamp bulbs some of which are defected, the defected proportion in box $C_1,C_2,C_3$ respectively are $1/2,1/8$ and $3/4$. A Box is selected random and the bulb is drawn from it... If the selected bulb is found to be defected. What is the probability that box $C_1$ is selected?

I got $4/13$ as answer. I proceeded by noting that, since $P(C_1), P(C_2), P(C_3)=1$ and
$$
\begin{split}
P(D/C_1) &= 1-1/2 = 1/2\\
P(D/C_2) &= 1-1/8 = 7/8\\
P(D/C_3) &= 1-3/4 = 1/4,
\end{split}
$$
this implies that
$$
\begin{split}
P(C_1/D) &= \frac{1\cdot 1/2}{1\cdot1/2+1\cdot 7/8+1\cdot 1/4} \\
   &= \frac{1\cdot 1/2}{1\cdot 1/2+1\cdot 7/8+1\cdot 1/4} \\      
  & =\frac{1/2}{13/8}\\
& = \frac{4}{13}.
\end{split}
$$
I got the answer as $4/13$, but in my text book the answer was showing as $4/11$ (Its an exercise problem, so in my text book explanation was not given).

Can someone confirm which answer is the right one and did I applied the right procedure?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  You'll get a lot more help if your questions are easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

You made a few mistakes:

First, you should have that $P(C_1)=P(C_2)=P(C_3)=\frac{1}{3}$.  Of course, you have that $P(C_1)+P(C_2)+P(C_3)=1$, but given that each box is picked with equal likelihood, that means that $P(C_1)=P(C_2)=P(C_3)=\frac{1}{3}$.  I wonder if with your use of $P(C_1),P(C_2),P(C_3)=1$ (what is the ',' here?), you managed to confuse yourself.

This, however, does not explain why you got a different answer, because in the formula, all those $\frac{1}{3}$'s cancel out.

You second mistake, however, is that you are given the proportions of the defective bulbs, so there is no need to subtract from $1$. That is, if you were given the proportion of good bulbs, then you have to subtract from $1$ to ge the proportion of defective ones, but that is not the case here. So, you immediately have: $P(D|C_1)=\frac{1}{2}$, $P(D|C_2)=\frac{1}{8}$, and $P(D|C_3)=\frac{3}{4}$

This explains the difference in answer. With your values, it does indeed work out to $\frac{4}{13}$, but if you use the correct values you get the answer of $\frac{4}{11}$ as given by the book.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Comment: @RaviRavee You're welcome! :)